# I am trying to use a select statment in javafx using mysql on multip tables

Tags: java, mysql

I have 6 tables I am selecting data from they are doginfo, dogat, sires, dams, owners, and coowners. Each table has a PK and each table has a dogid field. the dogid field identifies the individual dog and the other fields hold the recurring information that could apply to any dog ie many dogs could have the same color. I have verified that my select statement works with MySQL and I am now trying to get it to work in javafx.

My select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT doginfo.dogid, doginfo.regnum, doginfo.regname, doginfo.whelpdate, 
   dogat.breed, dogat.sex, dogat.color, sires.sireregname, 
   sires.sireregnum, dams.damregname, dams.damregnum, owners.firstname, 
   owners.lastname, coowners.coownernames, owners.address1, 
   owners.address2, owners.city, owners.zip, doginfo.dna, owners.htel, 
   owners.cell, doginfo.notes
FROM doginfo 
   LEFT JOIN dogat 
       ON doginfo.dogid = dogat.dogid
   LEFT JOIN sires 
       ON doginfo.dogid = sires.dogid
   LEFT JOIN dams 
       ON doginfo.dogid = dams.dogid
   LEFT JOIN owners 
       ON doginfo.dogid = owners.dogid
   LEFT JOIN coowners 
       ON doginfo.dogid = coowners.dogid
```

My code follows

```
    ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT doginfo.dogid,   doginfo.regnum, doginfo.regname, doginfo.whelpdate, dogat.breed, dogat.sex, dogat.color, sires.sireregname, 
+ " sires.sireregnum, dams.damregname, dams.damregnum, owners.firstname, owners.lastname, coowners.coownernames, owners.address1,"
+ "owners.address2, owners.city, owners.zip, doginfo.dna, owners.htel, owners.cell, doginfo.notes "
+ "FROM doginfo  LEFT JOIN dogat" 
+ ON doginfo.dogid = dogat.dogid"
+ LEFT JOIN sires" 
+ ON doginfo.dogid = sires.dogid"
+ LEFT JOIN dams "
+ ON doginfo.dogid = dams.dogid"
+ LEFT JOIN owners "
+ ON doginfo.dogid = owners.dogid"
+ LEFT JOIN coowners"
+ ON doginfo.dogid = coowners.dogid);
```

Starting at ON doginfo.dogid = dogat.dogid I get an error message ')' expected
cannot find symbol
symbol variable doginfo
location class FXMLDocumentController

unclosed string literal

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you search for unclosed string literal?

Comment: Yes I did figure it out with your suggestion thanks for the helping hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes on each line after the FROM

```
ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT doginfo.dogid, doginfo.regnum, doginfo.regname, doginfo.whelpdate, dogat.breed, dogat.sex, dogat.color, sires.sireregname, "
+ " sires.sireregnum, dams.damregname, dams.damregnum, owners.firstname, owners.lastname, coowners.coownernames, owners.address1,"
+ " owners.address2, owners.city, owners.zip, doginfo.dna, owners.htel, owners.cell, doginfo.notes "
+ " FROM doginfo  LEFT JOIN dogat" 
+ " ON doginfo.dogid = dogat.dogid"
+ " LEFT JOIN sires" 
+ " ON doginfo.dogid = sires.dogid"
+ " LEFT JOIN dams "
+ " ON doginfo.dogid = dams.dogid"
+ " LEFT JOIN owners "
+ " ON doginfo.dogid = owners.dogid"
+ " LEFT JOIN coowners"
+ " ON doginfo.dogid = coowners.dogid");
```